# Why is my MultipartFile is empty

Tags: java, file-upload

I passed the file convert to `MultipartFile`, but the `MultipartFile` is empty, please help to confirm it, thank you very much,
Code as follows:

```
File file = new File("/Users/aikaliu/document/micrown/source/img/20160802144001791.jpg");
    int fileSize =Integer.parseInt(file.length() + "");

    DiskFileItem fileItem = null;
    try {
        fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "text/plain", false, file.getName(),fileSize, file.getParentFile());
        fileItem.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    File file = new File("/Users/aikaliu/document/micrown/source/img/20160802144001791.jpg");

    final DiskFileItem diskFileItem = new DiskFileItem("fileData", "text/plain", true, file.getName(), 100000000, file.getParentFile());

    InputStream input = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(file);
        os = diskFileItem.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(input, os);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(diskFileItem);
```

Comment: I forgot IOUtils.copy in my code. You're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Can you switch to [MockMultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartFile.html) and try the code below?

```
File file = new File("/Users/aikaliu/document/micrown/source/img/20160802144001791.jpg");
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file",
file.getName(), "text/plain", IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
```

Comment: Thanks,but the MockMultipartFile Class in spring-test package , and Could not be used .

Comment: The use commons-file upload http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html